# Clear/Delete flash message in SF6

Tags: flash-message, symfony6

I'd like to delete/clear the FlashBag message container, impossible to find a way, certainly a method clear() with session...

Thx for help.

What I try in my controller :

$this->addFlash('success', 'message1');
$this->addFlash('success', 'message2');
HERE I WANT TO DEL THE 2 LAST
$this->addFlash('success', 'message3');

I'd like that only the message 3 is shown.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the solution:

```
$request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->clear();
```